# Cast chrome page on raspberry pi

Tags: google-chrome, casting, raspberry-pi, html

I'm searching for something to cast my web page on raspberry pi. I just found some modules to stream a link or a you tube video but i would to do as with the Chromecast and cast the own page.

Comment: The pi has a browser, why not just use it?

Comment: I tried but it's so slow.... It is for looking streaming football match